# Redirecting back and echoing result after form submit

Tags: php, html

I have got this code on page1.php:

```
<form action="mcgen.php" id="form1" method="POST">
<input style="margin-right:-160px;" name="name1" type="text" id="form-field-1" placeholder="username:password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $line ?>"> 
</div>
<button style="margin-right:-160px;" type="submit" name="gen" id="gen">Generate</button>
```

The mcgen.php file has this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['gen'])){                   
$f_contents = file("001.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
$data = $line;

list($first, $last) = explode(':', $line);
}
?>
```

I am trying to make it so after they click the "Generate" button it will run the code in mcgen.php and then return to page1.php and echo "$line".

Comment: What about using the same file?  So it submits to itself and echoes the result.

Comment: I didn't want to put it on the same files because there was abuse with refreshing the page and being able to resubmit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on mcgen.php

```
header('Location: page1.php?line='.$line);
```

on page1:

```
if (isset($_GET['line'])) {echo $_GET['line'];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your mcgen.php as a last line before } braces.

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='page1.php?q=your_var';</script>";
```

or you can use:

```
header("Location: page1.php?q=your_var");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also send the variables through header function on `mcgen.php`:

```
header('location: page1.php?first='.$first.'&last='.$last);
```